# How do I solve, Keyboard auto dismiss when we strat typing in text field in xamarin.ios app

Tags: xamarin, xamarin.ios

We are working on xamarin.ios app. Here we have design two different view one for portrait and another is landscape view in asingle view controller. Both view have a text field. We are loading view according to device orientation. Everything is good but when we start typing in text field, Keyboard up and auto dismiss while we type a very fist character. Again we focus on text field, keyboard appear but dismiss when we press any letter.
One thing that I have noticed, When we tap on keyboard key “ViewDidLayoutSubviews()” event call and view reloaded. 
Can you please guide me to solve this issue.

Comment: please post the relevant code

Answer (score 0, accepted):

We have solved it logically by using flags. We have declare a boolean flag isKeyboardAppear=false when view appear first. When keyboard appear we set this flag to true And we noticed ViewDidLayoutSubviews() method are calling on every key press, so we write this code

```
public override void ViewDidLayoutSubviews() 
{
 base.ViewDidLayoutSubviews(); 
 if (isKeyboardAppear == true) 
 { 
  return; 
 } 
}
```

When we hide keyboard manually we reset flag isKeyboardAppear=false .

Comment: Can you elaborate a bit, so it might become more helpful for future visitors?

Answer (score 0):

From what I can tell you are probably calling an event driven function when the text field is updated in such a way that it dismisses the keyboard? If this assumption is right, make sure that you are only adding the event to the text field once. Also make sure that the event you are calling isn't updating after every key stroke. You may need to use the event textbox.EditingDidEnd to run whatever function you want as soon as the user is no longer typing into the text field. I can update the answer with more specifics if i can see the actual code.

Comment: Edit: should use the event textbox.Ended. Using Textbox.Started may be your issue